# Wrong or missing date format and time in mails

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

In one MacOSX I found an issue with date and time while receiving mails from all my python scripts(in this case 2), where some are being received without any date, and others with a US format(month/day/year), not sure, and I want to use the day/month/year format, and others with wrong time. Seems to be almost random when it occurs.

For example in a **webmail** that I have installed in that server:

Mail 1: 
https://image.prntscr.com/image/d_-qJ0bjQj_p1W-bJkMQ4g.png

Mail 2:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/I14uoJBZT9aMjmDAr31zXA.png

Mail 3:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/9JSlEuogSoWDCGEefT5K-w.png

And other example in **thunderbird**:

Mail 1: 
https://image.prntscr.com/image/2n-I8y1aRl2BJSig5-yTPg.png

Mail 2:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/kjQRl0ooRfqNRr1hJ5YWSg.png

Mail 3: 
https://image.prntscr.com/image/0z_VhGgjRuSkcX_7kY6dbg.png

In **Gmail app** from android, I dont have this issue at all.

In both scripts I am using this to send:

```
#server = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server,25)
server = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server,587)
server.starttls()
server.login(smtp_auth_name,smtp_auth_pass)
subject = '%s_BACKUP job success made on %s' %(backup_identifier,server_name)
message = 'Current Config:\n%s\nStart time: %s\nFinish time: %s\nTarget path: %s\n\nStatus: \n\n%s\n\nBackup has been done.' %(current_config,inicial_date.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"),datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"),backup_folder,checkpoint)
message_structure = 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\nDate: %s\n\n%s' 
%(sender,email_receivers,subject,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%Ss"),message)             
server.sendmail(sender,email_receivers,message_structure)
server.quit()
logging.debug('Email notification as been send to: %s',email_receivers)
```

So seems that there is a problem with the atribution of date and time in mail clients, and my question is how can I use just the date and time from my mail server instead.

I know that there is the `formatdate(localtime=True)` but dont know how to setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems that I was able to bypass this problem by removing the Date field from:

```
   message_structure = 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s' 
    %(sender,email_receivers,subject,message)
```

Now seems that the date is added by the MTA, because it is the same in each email client now. I think that the previous date format was not handled properly by the server, leading to this problem.

I have been using that date format in one exchange server, and I didnt have any problem there, only in this Dovecot(MDA)+Postfix(MTA) server.